# PHP, html: How to pass the button value to post

Tags: php, html, post

I'm trying to pass in the value of the button to `$_POST["class_name"]` so I can use it in `selectclass.php`. I want to be able to click on the button in the table and have $_POST = the value of the button, or even better, if possible, the class_id next to the button. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
 <tbody>
            <form action="selectclass.php" method="post">
            <?php foreach ($classes as $class): ?>

                <tr>

                  <th><button type="text" name = "class_id"><?=$class["class_name"]?></button></th>
                  <th><?=$class["class_id"] ?></th>

                </tr>

         <?php endforeach ?>
         </form>
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to have a value, give it one using the `value` attribute:

```
<button type="text" name="class_id" value="some_value">
```

See [`<button>` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)